# How can I use Selenium to verify the href URL's are properly formed?

Tags: django, xpath, selenium

I'm trying to figure out how to use Django Selenium Webdriver to test that the href URL's on a particular page are correctly formed.

e.g. http://www.domain.com/post/12/test_post

So I want to test a regex like:

```
'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/test_post)$'
```

While I know the name of the post(slug), I don't know what the ID will be.
How can I use Selenium to test that the href URL's are correctly formed?

I tried:

```
self._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[matches(@href='/post/(/?P<id>\d+)/test_post')]")
```

But I get this error:

```
*** InvalidSelectiorException: Message: u'The given selector //a[matches(@href=\'/post/(/?P<id>\\d+)/test_post\')] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:\n[InvalidSelectorError] Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[matches(@href=\'/post/(/?P<id>\\d+)/test_post\')] because of the following error:\n[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "51" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR)"  location: "file:///var/folders/m
```

But I kept getting, ""The expression is not a legal expression."

```
self._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/post']")  
self._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, 'post/']")  
self._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/post/']")
```

Here I also got ""The expression is not a legal expression."

Is there a way I can verify that the href tags are properly formed?

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

It seems that you are not closing the parentheses of the method *matches*

Try:

```
self._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[matches(@href, '/post/(?P<id>\d+)/test_post')]")
```